# getting react state of component in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I am learning to create chrome extension and I have injected JavaScript file in the DOM.

Let say I have a `Counter` component with `count:0` and `toShow: false` as a state

I can get every element of DOM rendered by Counter etc using javascript code.

like basic `document.querySelectorAll()` etc works perfectly for DOM element. So i can access `count` state but as `toShow`  is not in real DOM I cannot see directly what is its value i.e is it true or false.

So I am having hard to access react virtual DOM using code.

React devtools is cool because I can select component and access everything of component using `$r`. But using javascript file etc injected from chrome  extension I cannot access devtools etc if i am not wrong.

Another way is to attach react component inside window object so that i can use it later but that is really a bad way as it is mudding the code.

Is there anyway I can access virtual dom using code without changing production code.

Thanks.